# Add a voltage offset to a resistor ladder R-2R

Tags: resistors, dac, r2r

I want a cheap DAC from a microcontroller for audio output. A resistor ladder is one solution. The output needs to be buffered by an op amp. Most op amps have some limitation on how close the input and output can be to the rails.

How can a resistor ladder be modified so that the output is some offset from the rails? Instead of 3.3V to 0V, I would like to limit the output to 3.0V to 0.3V without losing the 8-bits of resolution.

[image]

Comment: Well, do you understand how each enabled "bit" adds to the output voltage? Just create an artifical "bit" that adds the voltage you want to shift things.

Comment: PlasmaHH comment should be an answer. Do the scaling and offset in the microcontroller.

Comment: An artificial bit at the top limits me to half the range. An artificial bit at the bottom will only bias Vcc/2^(N+1). An artificial bit in the middle would cause all the bits beneath it to have their impact cut in half. It is a creative idea, but not the fit I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximately voltage of 0.27 V to 3.03 V at output

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSIHnd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I swapped out the 5R resistor for a cap so that only AC component gets through. Great bias idea

Answer (score 0):

May sound odd but just an idea:

Connect the leftmost 2R's one end to 0.3VDC instead of GND. And use 0.3VDC as logic-0 instead of 0V. This will offset the zero scale output to 0.3VDC. And the output voltage will be \$V_o = (Vref-0.3V)\cdot [code]/255\$.